# 90s (or earlier) horror novel switching point of view between escapee and a gang of other-wordly killers

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

This was a book that I read in about 1998.

The story opens with a scene in a teenager's bedroom, where a friend is sleeping over. There is the sound of breaking glass from downstairs; shortly after, the bedroom door opens, and the friend is run through with a pike and lifted out. The intruders smell of death, and seem to be covered in dead skin. The narrator (a girl if I remember correctly) survives as she is in the shadows. The rest of the family is raped and murdered. It's not actually supernatural, but the gang of killers initially appear to be monsters, or other-worldly.

Thereafter the point of view switches with each chapter between the surviving girl and one of the gang members.

The title of the book was something like "The Longest Night" or "The Long Day". I can't remember the author's name. I think the story takes place over about 24 hours, but am not sure.

Comment: Are there any sci fi or fantasy elements to the book? It doesn't sound like it from what you describe. Unfortunately, if it doesn't, it's off-topic here.

Comment: The book appears to be supernatural from the opening. The killers appear to be monsters, or other-worldly. Perhaps that's too tenuous. Sorry.

Comment: @Rhubbarb: You should edit your question to make the supernatural element more obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is [*Endless Night*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/147590.Endless_Night) (1993) by Richard Laymon.

> Jody is pretty tough for a sixteen-year-old girl. That's the only reason she's still alive - for now. She was sleeping over at her friend Evelyn's house when a group of killers broke in and tried to slaughter everyone. She saw Evelyn spitted on a spear, but Jody managed to escape, along with Evelyn's little brother, Andy. — Simon was one of the killers that gruesome night. His friends have left it up to him to find the only living witnesses to their massacre. Or else they'll butcher his family next. But Simon has his own reasons for wanting to get his hands on Jody...

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: As @Wikis suggested: Stating the "answer" in the form of a one-liner might - despite being 100% correct (I wouldn't know) - lead to downvotes. Once you have accumulated enough reputation, you could use this form maybe as a comment, ensuring you are on the right track, but as an answer it's not flashed out enough. Quotes, maybe just from the blurb but maybe also from the text itself linked with the scenes the OP mentions in the questions could make this an excellent answer. Incidentally, welcome to SFF.SE

Comment: I probably ought to have let David do it on his own, but it's a good match, and I think that, if I don't do it now, it will slip away and it will stay a bad answer.

Comment: David Welch and @SeanDuggan: Fantastic. It was indeed *Endless Night* by Richard Laymon. My friend that loaned this to me died so I could not ask him, sadly. I've been trying to recall that for many years. I'm glad to see that I was not too far from the title. Now, I can buy myself a copy. I am immensely pleased to be able to do this now; thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

The book is *Intensity* (1987) by Dean Koontz. Fantastic book!

It is only about one killer though (if it is the same book that I am thinking of). The killer is Edger Vess and he also has a captive young girl in a secret room in the basement and has trained dobermans... great book if it's the same one... if not, I highly recommend it.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32439.Intensity?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=9TnZ6069Iy&rank=1):

> Past midnight, Chyna Shepard, twenty-six, gazes out a moonlit window, unable to sleep on her first night in the Napa Valley home of her best friend's family. Instinct proves reliable. A murderous sociopath, Edgler Foreman Vess, has entered the house, intent on killing everyone inside. A self-proclaimed "homicidal adventurer," Vess lives only to satisfy all appetites as they arise, to immerse himself in sensation, to live without fear, remorse or limits, to live with "intensity." Chyna is trapped in his deadly orbit.
>
> Chyna is a survivor, toughened by a lifelong struggle for safety and self-respect. Now she will be tested as never before. At first her sole aim is to get out alive--until, by chance, she learns the identity of Vess's next intended victim, a faraway innocent only she can save. Driven by a newly discovered thirst for meaning beyond mere self-preservation, Chyna musters every inner resource she has to save an endangered girl...as moment by moment, the terrifying threat of Edgler Foreman Vess intensifies.